# How to build an Auction in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to build an auction in R Shiny. Obviously it should be able to handle many users and I need to traditional English, Dutch and Japanese auctions. Anyone tried this?

Sorry for the lack of code as I don't really know where to start.

Thanks

Comment: Hello, could you at least specify the features you want? (multiple connections to a single server? financial auctions or scientific interest? what are the users' possibilities?) Even if you don't give code examples, explain a bit what is your project, please.

Comment: maybe this could be a starting point: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56463169/can-r-shiny-display-different-views-for-two-simultaneous-users-interacting-with/56465326#56465326?